# How to catch ADSLOGSTR in self-written c++ app (not only in TwinCAT XAE)

Tags: c++, twincat

I am developing a user application which need to interact with the PLC using the ADS protocol.

Inside a PLC application I have the following code:

```
IF bSendMessage THEN
    ADSLOGSTR(
        msgCtrlMask := ADSLOG_MSGTYPE_ERROR,
        msgFmtStr := 'This is an error: %s', 
        strArg := 'Details');
END_IF;
```

I see the message perfectly inside the TwinCAT XAE output window. Using the provided ADS-c++ examples from github/infosys, I managed to read from and write to variables and get notifications when a variable changed.

However, I cannot find out how to catch the message inside my application.

SOLUTION:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <conio.h>

// ADS headers for TwinCAT 3
#include "C:\TwinCAT\AdsApi\TcAdsDll\Include\TcAdsDef.h"
#include "C:\TwinCAT\AdsApi\TcAdsDll\Include\TcAdsAPI.h"

int main()
{
    long error(0);

    // Open communication port on the ADS router
    AdsPortOpen();

    AmsAddr addr = {
        { 41, 249, 209, 138, 1, 1 },
        AMSPORT_LOGGER
    };

    try
    {
        unsigned long index_group = 1;
        unsigned long index_offset = 0xffff;
        AdsNotificationAttrib attr = {
            .cbLength = 1024,
            .nTransMode = ADSTRANS_SERVERCYCLE,
            .nMaxDelay = 0,
            .nCycleTime = 0
        };

        // subscribe to logger
        unsigned long notification_handle(0);
        error = AdsSyncAddDeviceNotificationReq(
            &addr, index_group, index_offset, &attr,
            [](AmsAddr* addr, AdsNotificationHeader* notification, unsigned long handle) {
                std::string message((char*)(notification->data + 16), notification->cbSampleSize - 16);
                std::cout << message << std::endl;
            },
            0, &notification_handle);

        if (error != 0) {
            throw new std::runtime_error("Subscription to Logger failed");
        }

        // wait until keypressed
        std::cout << "Wait until keypressed" << std::endl;
        _getch();

        // finish subscription
        error = AdsSyncDelDeviceNotificationReq(&addr, notification_handle);
        if (error != 0) {
            throw new std::runtime_error("Unsubscription from Logger failed");
        }

    }
    catch (...)
    {
    }

    // Close communication port
    AdsPortClose();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't have an answer in C++ so I'm just adding a comment. I solved this in Node.js year ago and wrote a blog post about it. See if it helps: https://jisotalo.fi/subscribing-to-twincat-logger-in-nodejs

Comment: This is (almost) exactly what I needed. With this info I can figure it out using c++. Thank you very much!

Comment: Glad to hear! If you solve it in C++ it might be useful to add an answer here later :)